Getting rid of Google sign-in prompt
How do I stop the Google sign-in prompt when I don't have a Google account?
Using macOS Sonoma on Mac Pro (Late 2013).


What service is asking for a Google login?  macOS doesn't know or care about a Google login by default.

I was using eBay.

But it has happened sporadically on other sites.

Still not an Apple thing.  Lots of web sites out there support logging in through Google.

I think its a mistake calling it  a prompt.  I get it it on more and more sites, but its just an option.

Royston, can you please add a screenshot of such a prompt?

@RohitGupta The OP might see an actual prompt, not just a sign in with google option.

If it's an option, how do I opt out?

You have a catch-22 in that until you log into whatever web site, it is going to be prompting you with all the login methods it supports.  This is not something the OS (macOS, WIndows, Linux, what have you) can do for you.
